# Module version mismatch composer-connector-hlfv1

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I keep getting a "module version mismatch" error when walking through the developer guide tutorial.   I'm able to complete almost all of the tutorial (creating and testing my business network, deploying it to local fabric, interacting with it via the rest server), but get an error when running yeoman to create the sample angular app...

```
~/git/my-test-network$ yo hyperledger-composer:angular
Welcome to the Hyperledger Composer Angular project generator
? Do you want to connect to a running Business Network? Yes
? Project name: my-app
? Description: Commodity
? Author name: t
? Author email: t
? License: Apache-2.0
? Business network identifier: my-test-network
? Connection profile: hlfv1
? Enrollment ID: admin
? Enrollment secret: adminpw
? Do you want to generate a new REST API or connect to an existing REST API?         Generate a new REST API
? REST server port: 4000
? Should namespaces be used in the generated REST API? Never use namespaces
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Failed to load connector module "composer-connector-hlfv1" for connection profile "hlfv1". Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 48, got 46.
at connectionProfileStore.load.then.e (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/composer-common/lib/connectionprofilemanager.js:150:38)
```

I believe this is related to npm, but I have uninstalled/reinstalled/rebuild several times and the error persists

```
npm uninstall -g composer-cli
npm uninstall -g composer-rest-server
npm uninstall -g generator-fabric-composer
npm install -g composer-cli
npm install -g composer-rest-server
npm install -g generator-fabric-composer
npm uninstall -g yo
npm install -g yo
```

my setup ...

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

docker --version    Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87
docker-compose --version    docker-compose version 1.8.0, build unknown
node --version  v6.11.1
npm --version   5.3.0

npm -v composer-cli 5.3.0
npm -v composer-rest-server 5.3.0
npm -v generator-hyperledger-composer   5.3.0
npm -v yo 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the output from `composer -v`

You should be using `generator-hyperledger-composer` Above I see you installed the old version: `npm install -g generator-fabric-composer`

Can you please `cd` into the generated app and `rm -r` the `node_modules` directory, and then rerun `npm install`.